# Find duplicates and update T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table

```
TABLE GrantedService(
 GUID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PK,   
 ServiceTypeGUID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 ServiceOrderGUID [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 ValidFrom datetime
 ValidTo datetime
 Description [varchar](max) NULL,
 ExternalID [varchar](40) NULL
)
```

This table contains duplicates where the duplicate is a combination of ServiceTypeGUID and ServiceOrderGUID. I.E. the same ServiceTypeGUID should not appear multiple times with the same ServiceOrderGUID, which it currently does.

What I need is to locate the duplicates and set ValidTo as the ValidFrom date from the duplicate with the highest ExternalID and leave its ValidTo date as null.

I started with finding the duplicates like this:

```
with x as(

select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() 
over(PARTITION by ServiceTypeGUID,ServiceOrderGUID order by ExternalID DESC) 
from GrantedService where ValidTo is null

)select * from x where rn>1
```

Any ideas on how to proceed from here or any other method?

Comment: @Scoregraphic . . . This isn't a duplicate of removing duplicate rows, if only because this is about *updating* duplicates not *deleting* them.

Comment: I retracted my vote then as you updated the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "ValidFrom date from the duplicate with the highest ExternalID" is the maximum of `ValidFrom`, you can do this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select *,
             ROW_NUMBER() as seqnum over (partition by ServiceTypeGUID, ServiceOrderGUID
                                          order by ExternalID DESC
                                         ),
             max(validfrom) over (partition by ServiceTypeGUID, ServiceOrderGUID) as maxValidFrom
     from GrantedService
     where ValidTo is null
    )
update toupdate
    set ValidTo = maxValidFrom
    where seqnum > 1 and ValidTo is NULL;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `first_value()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select *,
             ROW_NUMBER() as seqnum over (partition by ServiceTypeGUID, ServiceOrderGUID
                                          order by ExternalID DESC
                                         ),
             first_value(validfrom) over (partition by ServiceTypeGUID, ServiceOrderGUID
                                          order by ExternalID DESC
                                         ) as lastValidFrom
     from GrantedService
     where ValidTo is null
    )
update toupdate
    set ValidTo = maxValidFrom
    where seqnum > 1;
```

If neither of these conditions are true, the query is a bit more complicated but still possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes the record with the highest externalid value should also have the latest ValidFrom date. Its SQL 2008. i will try out your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a good one, you just need to use DELETE rather than SELECT at the end.

```
WITH x AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceTypeGUID, ServiceOrderGUID
ORDER BY ExternalID DESC) 
FROM GrantedService WHERE ValidTo IS NULL
) DELETE FROM x WHERE RN > 1
```

I'd use your SELECT with WHERE RN > 1 to make sure that the duplicate rows you're expecting are going to be deleted with your DELETE.